# How do I make a section scroll to fit content in the Polymer Designer Tool?

Tags: responsive-design, polymer, polymer-designer-tool

I know very little about programming, but I'm excited about the prospect of Polymer making these advanced objects as simple as working in an HTML doc. Anyway, there's some basic stuff I can't figure out, like how to get a section to scroll to fit nested content, like a bunch of cards.

[Here's an example](http://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/preview.html#471bd0d45d429a61638f)

In a full, widescreen monitor, all 8 cards on the "100 years" tab are displayed fine. But as soon as you resize the window to something much narrower, like a smartphone screen, you realize you can't scroll, and thus can't access all of the content.

How do I enable scrolling for this?

Answer (score 1):

The `core-animated-pages` element is `overflow: hidden`, and all the visible elements are children of that element.

If you set the `core-animated-pages` element to overflow: auto, then it will be scrollable.